# PHP using xampp Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, sql

For some reason it is giving me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)
code:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM posts, users 
WHERE posts.userID = users.userID ORDER BY postTimestamp";          
$result = mysqli_query($connection $query);
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection,$query);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to use the ',' in `$result`

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is comma that you have forgotten:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM posts, users 
WHERE posts.userID = users.userID ORDER BY postTimestamp";          
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```